# Capture the keyboard in the game？

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keyboard, hook

I am trying to use unity3d to do a button monitoring function, but now I have encountered some difficulties.
My first version of the method is to do it through hook, everything is ok, until I encounter League of Legends, on the interface of this game, my keyboard cannot be captured by hook. The main code like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelHookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

public delegate IntPtr LowLevelHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);
```

Next, I used the DirectX input component to monitor. Similarly, there was no response on the League of Legends interface. By the way, I am using SharpDX.DirectInput. The code like this:

```
Keyboard keyboard;

void Start()
{
    var directInput = new DirectInput();
    keyboard = new Keyboard(directInput);
    keyboard.Acquire();
}

void Update()
{
    KeyboardState cur = keyboard.GetCurrentState();
    if (cur.PressedKeys.Count != 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError(cur.ToString());
    }
}
```

Finally I used GetAsyncKeyState to capture, the same does not take effect.

So does anyone know what's going on? This kind of imagination should not only lie in League of Legends, but also in other games. I haven't had time to test it. If you have any ideas or suggestions, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Some high budget games have anti-cheat systems. I believe you have to run your program as admin in order to do the button monitoring.

Comment: Yes! Oh my God, I thought there was something wrong with my code, I think I wasted a lot of time ~ thank you very much!

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please accept it, which marks the problem as solved in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the question in comment section:

> Some high budget games have anti-cheat systems. You have to run your
> program as administrator in order to do the button monitoring.

Comment: Yes, and also one more thing is if you can set your app to start as admin rather than manually doing it, that would be useful for the user's experience.

Comment: AFAIK there are no built-in solutions in Unity for this. You should try to run something that require admin rights, the OS (Windows, I assume) will prompt you automatically. There are ways to force it to always get admin rights at start by manually configuring the manifest of the .NET program. This is however a complete another question. You may make another post, or just do some research on the internet. People have asked about this before.